Why did this simple lead-acid battery charger fail?
The following schematic shows the simple circuit of an LED lantern. One day somebody connects it to the mains supply in order to recharge the battery after several months, but hears a loud sound!
The C2 capacitor is dead, the resistor R6 is completely burned and discolored and the battery has an abscess-like bulge and is somewhat deformed. Everything else, including the fuse, seems healthy. I'm a little surprised that R6 is burned completely but the red LED indicator is not damaged.
One of the things I'd like to know is how the voltage across C2 can be calculated for the case when the battery is charging.
Did the circuit fail because the voltage of C2 was too high? If the battery had been almost full, wouldn't the circuit have failed?
Some details:

D5, D6, D7 seem to be Germanium diodes (the forward voltage drop is 0.2 V when measured with DMM)
DC+ and DC- terminals are for charging from DC input
The battery seems to be a 4 V 1600 mAh lead-acid battery


simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

@vir, The appliance has no transformer. I'm sure.

@vir, Maybe some sort of voltage divider is formed in the circuit.

Oh yes, it's a capacitive dropper circuit. That's my mistake.

Those are almost certainly not germanium diodes. You can barely even get germanium diodes anymore, and those that you can are very expensive and prone to failure. They're probably silicon Schottky diodes, which have similar characteristics, are much cheaper, and are more robust.

That is a very dangerous lamp which definitely wouldn't pass any safety inspections, and if your house were to catch on fire because of it, your insurance might not cover it.
The maximum voltage on C2 is ONLY limited by the battery, and if the battery were to get disconnected or its internal resistance became significantly higher, the voltage across the C2 would also go much higher.
That circuit uses the input capacitor marked as 225J400V (2.2uF, 400Vdc) as a "capacitive dropper", meaning it uses that capacitor's capacitive reactance to reduce the input current (but NOT the voltage), so in series with a sufficient load that capacitor will act like voltage divider.
Its ONLY advantage is that it is not providing DIRECT connection to the power from the outlet and that it does not waste power in the form of heat like a resistor (main reason why they use capacitor instead of resistor), but the voltage and current passing through it are still sufficient to KILL a person!!
Besides that, this type of charger is VERY INEFFICIENT: it literally takes the same amount of current at the full outlet voltage as the device which uses it (in this case the battery and the lamp) but the device works at many times lower voltage, which would a transformer-based power supply/charger convert so that the input current would be that many times reduced, significantly reducing the load on the power lines.
I had miss-worded my explanation previously, stating that most of the power would be wasted in this supply due to that current, but in reality most of that power would be going back and forth between the capacitor and the power utility generators, resulting in an unnecessary extraneous current which adds to the power line losses.
This is known as a low Power Factor (ratio of actual power used vs. the apparent power flowing through the wires).
(Thank you "TRANSISTOR" for correcting me.)
The resistor in parallel with that capacitor serves to reduce voltage spikes across it and to discharge it when unplugged.
D5, D6 and D7 are possibly burned/fused and thus show low voltage drop, or they could be Schottky diodes. I haven't seen Germanium diodes in use for a long, long time.
MY NUMBER ONE ADVICE TO YOU IS: NEVER BUY OR USE DEVICES LIKE THIS ONE if you care about your life and home!!!
Just salvage the parts and get a proper one that uses a transformer, whether the old classic iron core or the new switching ferrite core type!
I have mentioned this in a comment, but I will add it here:
My cousin gave me a small lamp with a similar design, also using a capacitive dropper, but they placed just the plain ALKALINE, non-rechargeable cells inside, and they leaked and it all failed, of course. He is lucky he didn't get injured or his house set on fire. The incredibly dumb and dangerous devices are being made and sold by some criminally irresponsible Chinese makers and merchants, and there should be some VERY serious legal consequences for that.

I agree. I'm thinking overcharging (inevitable with this design), gas generation, battery seal failure, water loss, battery resistance increase, extreme overvoltage from battery current way below spec, overvoltage on C2, overcurrent on R6.

"... VERY INEFFICIENT, basically wasting the difference in voltage between your outlet and battery voltage, so 116V out of 120V go to waste ..." You might want to reword that. The voltage and current in the capacitor are at 90° so the power dissipation in the capacitor is close to zero. Or have I misread your explanation?

@vir Also, my cousin gave a small lamp with a similar design, also using a capacitive dropper, but they placed just the plain ALKALINE, non-rechargeable cells inside, and they leaked and it all failed, of course. He is lucky he didn't get injured or his house set on fire. The incredibly dumb and dangerous devices are being made and sold by some criminally irresponsible Chinese makers and merchants, and there should be some VERY serious legal consequences for that.

Also I have a friend in subrogation law who tells me that homeowner's/renter's insurance (at least in the US) will still pay out unless they can prove that you intentionally burned your house down. He's been dealing with a lot of cases of people rolling their own e-bike batteries lately.

@Transistor Thank you for catching that, I will re-word it. I am aware that the capacitor itself is not wasting almost any energy, but whatever the current required for the device at its low voltage is also the same amount of current required at the power outlet voltage, but due to the capacitive reactance that current mostly goes back and forth through the power lines and we have, as you know, an extremely low Power Factor.

"and if your house were to catch on fire because of it, your insurance might not cover it." - Do you have a source for that? I hear similar arguments trotted out sometimes, but I have yet to learn about an actual case of this happening.

@marcelm Your comment stands, but the fact that these devices are actually dangerous should be enough to ban them and fine those who make and sell them.
